# How can I bind a Label's textFillProperty?

Tags: javafx, label, bind

I have a class called StatusContext that multiple packages use to display a status/error to the main window using a Label. They did this by binding to the Label's text property. I'd like to add a color setting to StatusContext so I can change the Label's textFill color based on the status/error that is set. I can't figure out how to go about it and bind to the Label's textFillProperty.

**FXMLDocument.fxml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" fx:controller="labelbindtest.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="textButton" layoutX="93.0" layoutY="88.0" onAction="#handleTextButtonAction" text="Show Error" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="122.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <Button fx:id="colorButton" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="88.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleColorButtonAction" text="Set Error RED" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FXMLDocumentController.java:**

```
package labelbindtest;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button textButton;
    @FXML    
    private Button colorButton;
    @FXML
    private void handleColorButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // Something like StatusContext.setColor(Color.RED); ??
    }
    @FXML
    private void handleTextButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        StatusContext.setStatus("Here's the error");
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        label.textProperty().bind(StatusContext.getProperty());
        // Something like label.textFillProperty().bind(StatusContext.getColor()); ??
    }
}
```

**LabelBindTest.java:**

```
package labelbindtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabelBindTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**StatusContext.java:**

```
package labelbindtest;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class StatusContext {
    private static final SimpleStringProperty status = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public static SimpleStringProperty getProperty(){
        return status;
    }

    public static void clear(){
        status.setValue("");
    }

    public static void setStatus(String st){
        status.setValue(st);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Slaw I'm still learning the right format for posting. I almost had it right this time :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a listener to the textProperty and handle the value when it changes.

E.g.:

```
    label.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue)->{
        switch(newValue){
            case "yourValue":
                label.setTextFill(Color.AQUA);
                break;
            //Your rules    
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much @josev.junior That did the trick. I prepend the messages with the either INFO, WARN or ERRO and do the switch on the first 4 characters of the message to set the color and it works perfectly.